# Isometries of Metric Spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

For a metric space $(X,d)$, let $\def\Iso{\operatorname{Iso}}\Iso(X,d)$ denote the group of bijective isometries of $(X,d)$. Clearly, $\Iso(X,d)$ is a group under composition.

**Question:** Let $X$ be a space with two [equivalent metrics](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquivalentMetrics.html) $d_1$ and $d_2$. Is it true that $\Iso(X,d_1)$ and $\Iso(X,d_2)$ are isomorphic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the set $X=\{0,1,2\}$ with the metric $d$ inherited from the usual Euclidean metric and the metric $d'$ defined by

$$d'(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=y\\
1,&\text{if }x\ne y\;.
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

Every permutation of $X$ is in $\operatorname{Iso}(X,d')$, but $\operatorname{Iso}(X,d)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

For an infinite example, let $X=\{2^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, let $d$ be the usual metric, and let $d'$ be the discrete metric as in $(1)$: $\operatorname{Iso}(X,d)$ is trivial, while $\operatorname{Iso}(X,d')$ is isomorphic to the group of permutations of $\Bbb N$.